# Combining multiple IF/AND/THEN statements Part 2

Tags: excel, excel-2013

After having solved the initial programming question by using the following calculation...

```
=IF(OR(AND($D11="Long",$M11>=$N11),AND($D11="Short",$M11<=$N11)),"Win","Loss")
```

The secondary question relates to when D11 is blank.  I have tried a number of ways including using `ISBLANK` in tring to include this in the calculation.

The calculation will reside in R11.  So written out... IF D11 is blank then blank otherwise the above calculation will take place.  Not sure how to place this within the above calculation to make it work.  My efforts have been incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add that first, in this generic form

`=IF($D11="","",your_formula)`

so specifically that becomes:

`=IF($D11="","",IF(OR(AND($D11="Long",$M11>=$N11),AND($D11="Short",$M11<=$N11)), "Win","Loss"))`

see screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I tried that, but let me try that once again.  I may have missed an element.

Comment: @barry_houdini... the above calculation returns an error.  The error comes back as "The formula you typed contains an error."  Then, it goes on to say "*For information about fixing common formula problems, click Help. *To get assistance in entering a function, click Function Wizard (Formulas tab, Function Library group). * If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (')."     Not exactly sure where the error is????

Comment: It works fine for me - I just copied and pasted from above and it works straight off - I'll add a screenshot above

Comment: I cleared all contents and re-copied the calculation.  All is well.  Thanks so much Barry!